# Persisting vuex modules into storage in nativescript-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

In my nativescript-vue app I want to persist to application settings storage a selected number of modules, in the tutorial below it shows how to do this using subscribe to all mutations, this saves all info and I only want a few modules to save.

This is the nativescript-storage library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-localstorage

And medium tutorial:

https://medium.com/@gcuencamoncin/how-to-make-vuex-persistent-in-our-nativescript-vue-application-7a35de22dd55

```
const NSVuexPersistent = store => {
 // Init hook.
 let storageStr = localStorage.getItem('ns-vuex-persistent');
 if (storageStr) {
  store.replaceState(JSON.parse(storageStr))
 }
 store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  // Suscribe hook.
  localStorage.setItem('ns-vuex-persistent', JSON.stringify(state));
 })
};
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible, if you have any issue please add more details of it.

Comment: If I have a module Modal and state cookiesAccepted how can I store only that state?